# Angry Wolves on Demand!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever I use the summon command to spawn an angry wolf using `/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Angry:1}`, it always spawns neutral, and does not agro on to me. Would I have to force the player to right click the wolf (if you can even do that)? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make wolves angry at an arbitrary player. What you can do is make them angry at a specific target, but only if you know their name/UUID. For example, causing a snowball with a custom "thrower" (via `ownerName` tag) to hit a wolf will cause it to become angry at that specified target.

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~
/summon Snowball ~ ~5 ~ {ownerName:"Skylinerw"}
```

However, since a target selector cannot be used here, you must know the name of the player.

---

In 1.9, when a mob is the passenger of another mob, they will take control of the pathfinding of its host. While this does not include causing the host to attack the target, the rider itself can do that instead.

For example, the following summons a wolf that is being controlled by a zombie. The wolf will get within melee range of the player and the zombie itself will attack. Note that this does not give the wolf the "angry" skin.

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Zombie",Silent:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in creative mode?

> Wolves will only remain angry as long as they have something to attack. Summoning an angry wolf will immediately make it non-angry since it doesn't have a target.

[Source.](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-33558?focusedCommentId=182218&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-182218)

Comment: I summoned it first in creative then switched to gmode 2, and it didnt work. Then I summoned it strait from gmode 2 and it still didnt work. I tied both in a command block and from the chat.

Comment: Try to see if the wolf becomes angry at you if you are in survival. (Drink regen potion if necessary)

Comment: Still didnt work... no real solution then?

Comment: It's a bug. https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-33558?focusedCommentId=182218&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-182218